# Multiple database records with one form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently creating a survey where the user is able to choose from four different options for every category. For example:

Category 1: [X] Option 1 – [] Option 2 – [] Option 3 – [] Option 4

What I have so far is a table with categories. There I have the names of the categories and some extra info for each category.

Additionally I have a survey controller with the form where every category with the options is listed (eaches through the category table entries). The survey table holds the `value` (option 1, 2, 3 or 4), the `category_id` as well as the `user_id`. What I want to achieve now is that it creates multiple database records in the survey table for each category the user fills out basically with one form (?).

I had the idea to each through the categories and have the form within the each, the problem is that I will have 25 different forms and every form has its own submit button. I could fiddle around with JS and hide every button expect the last but that seems like a bad idea.

**What would be the best solution for the problem I am facing?**

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you checked the Rails Guides, section for nested forms: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Comment: Thanks.  How will I be able to make the options as radio buttons individually selectable for every category? Since the input value is always the same I cant select the option for each category but only once in general for every category overall.